# bad operand types for binary operator '<=' on for loop array int

Tags: java

why do i get bad operand types for binary operator '<=' when i in a for loop says i <= prices

```
  static long calculateAmount(int[] prices) {
    long total = 0;
    int[] items;
 for(int i=0; i <= prices; i++){
     items[i] = prices[i];
     if(i == 2){
         int newprice = prices[i] - prices[1];
         if(prices[i] - prices[1] <= 0){
         total = total + prices[i] - prices[i];
         }
     }
     else if(i >= 3){
         int lowest = 0;
         for(int j=0; i <= items; i++){
             if(items[i] < lowest || lowest == 0){
                 lowest = items[i]; 
             }
             total = total + lowest;
         }
     }

 }
    return total;

}
```

for me it makes no sense at all? i am just saying that aslong as i is less then prices keep going?

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense to compare a number to an array?

Comment: `i <= prices.length`

Comment: items is an array, you can t compare an int with an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prices is an array. You cannot compare int with array. I think you want to compare i with array length like `i < prices.length`

Answer (score -1):

You pass in `prices` as `int[] prices` -- an array, but you're trying to compare with `i` -- an int.